# New Concrete Patio Options

Tags: concrete

We would like to put in a new concrete patio.  We are looking at a stamped concrete patio for durability and visual appeal.  What other options are there?  What are the pros and cons of the different options?

In addition, what about staining concrete?  What is the durability?  Does it need to be reapplied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We chose to do stamped and colored concrete, because we liked the look and the low maintenance.  We are not doing it ourselves.  We have hired out on this one.

Answer (score 1):

the other option, you can make tile patio with a design of mosaic, that is quiet cool... : )

Answer (score 0):

I had a new patio laid by a mason with fiber mesh concrete. It has a nice picture frame edge. It'll probably run you between $200-400 for a yard or so of concrete plus labor. Not sure how big you want to make it. Fiber mesh does not require rebar and is stronger. I love my new patio. You'll have some fibers sticking out for a while, but they go away eventually.